# Yii2 kartik widget FileInput column type

Tags: php, yii2

Reading the documentation for the Yii2 kartik widget FileInput I can't find any detail about the field type the data should be stored in.

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput

Should I be using a BLOB field or STRING?

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing your file on the file system then you should use `string` data type as you will only be storing the name of the file. But if you are encoding your file then you should use `blob`.